# How to Fail an Oracle stored procedure when a record count in a table reaches a threshold

Tags: oracle, plsql

Could you please let me know how I can fail an Oracle stored procedure if the count of records in Table1 is greater than 300 records?

Should I use custom exception handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test
IS
   D_count_exceeded   EXCEPTION;
   D_Count            NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO d_count FROM your_table;

   IF D_count > 300 THEN
      RAISE D_Count_Exceeded;
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger that raises an exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOO_MANY_RECS_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT ON SOME_TABLE
  -- Note: *not* FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nCount  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nCount
    FROM SOME_TABLE;

  IF nCount >= 300 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Too many records (' || nCount ||
                                    ') found in SOME_TABLE');
  END IF;
END TOO_MANY_RECS_TRIGGER;
```

Share and enjoy.